# Have Email Alerts stop working?

Tags: email, workflow, email-template

Is any one else experiencing issues with Email Alerts? All the Email Alerts have stop working in all our subscriber Orgs, the workflow runs (we validated by adding other actions) but the email is never sent (Even with a "Hello World" plain text).

The email can be sent from Apex code without a problem, if we try to send it from the process builder we get the error "Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients" which makes no sense since there are emails available and there is a valid recipient with a valid email in the record.

Comment: Have you checked the trust if there are any recent issues? you can use this status link https://status.salesforce.com/ to check the status of your instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was with the workflow itself, someone turned on multi currency in our packaging org breaking a lot of workflows since it added the only active currency (USD) to the condition.

And sadly we are also having unrelated problems ("Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients") sending emails in some of the orgs where we clone and modify the workflow to test it was working, Support is currently investigating this issue.

The solution was to change the workflows rule criteria from `field criteria (default)` to `formula evaluates to true` (which doesn't enforce currency restrictions apparently)

Answer (score 2):

Above error message occurs when there a blank email field specified on the recipient list and if the intended user is inactive.

Review resolution steps mentioned on [Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320056&type=1&mode=1).

Also,  There is a [Known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkxwQAA) for user lookups unavailable as recipients for email alerts.

Thanks,